# Name of the connector used in Z axis stop IC

Tags: identification, connector

What is the name of the connector used for Z axis stop switch IC used in 3D printers?

Here is the picture of the IC:

[image: Z Axis stop switch]

I saw this [IC on Amazon](https://www.amazon.in/Tesseract-Printer-Accessories-Switch-Creality/dp/B08QNGTRLH/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1Y1F7I39GMOY2&keywords=z+axis+stop&qid=1636099247&sprefix=z+axis+stop%2Caps%2C321&sr=8-1)

Comment: Looks like a microswitch used as a limit switch, not an IC.

Comment: As others have said it's not an IC, what they have not said is what it actually is:  it's a PCBA (printed circuit board assembly)

Answer (score 3):

That is a 3 pin JST XH series connector.  These are used on 3D printers (such as the Ender 3) as limit switches.

[Here is the housing that fits it.](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/XHP-3/1651017)  You will need to buy terminals as well.

Note that this is not an IC.  It is a limit switch.

Comment: Thanks for info :-)